# Add a class at specific elemnt in Menu Walker

Tags: wordpress, menu, html-lists

I have customised my menu in wordpress by extending the Nav_Menu_Walker class and now i cannot figure it out how could i add a class at a specific ul element. I have this function which adds classes by depth:

```
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
 $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
 if ($depth >= 1)
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"subsubmenu\">\n";
 else
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"submenu\">\n";

}
```

When the $depth is 0 i would like to add a different class at the third element from $depth =0 rather than "submenu".

Could you please provide me some suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args )
```

or you can refer to this link for the Nav Menu Walker integration : http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/3097

Cheers!